# Display data from mysql database using a table

Tags: mysql, database

I have table of items and I want to display all the item in a table form. Each row must contain a maximum of 3 cells. How can I do that?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM newrequest";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<table>

    <tr>";

    While($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {    

            $query_two = "SELECT * FROM tblmember WHERE customer_id = '${row['customer_id']}'";
            $result_two = mysql_query($query_two);
            $username = mysql_fetch_array($result_two)['username'];


echo "

<td>               <p><b>Advertised by:</b> " .$username . " </p>

                  <img src= ".$row['location']." style= width:300px;   >

                  <p><b>Product name:</b>" .$row['product_name'] . "</p>

                  <p><b>Product price:</b>" . $row['price'] . "</p>


</td>";
}

echo "</tr>
</table>";


mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
echo '<table>';

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $query_two = "SELECT * FROM tblmember WHERE customer_id = '${row['customer_id']}'";
    $result_two = mysql_query($query_two);
    $username = mysql_fetch_array($result_two)['username'];

    $flag = false;
    if($i%3 == 1) echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>
                        <td><img src="'.$row['location'].'" style="width:300px;"/>
                        <p><b>Product name:</b>' .$row['product_name'] . '</p>
                        <p><b>Product price:</b>' . $row['price'] . '</p></td>
                      </td>';
    if($i%3 == 0) {
        $flag = true;
        echo '</tr>';
    }
$i++;
}
if(!$flag) echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: this will display image,product name and price separately,I need to have them all in a single cell

Comment: Edited... it's in one cell now.

Comment: No its displaying one cell per row

Comment: What? You said "I need to have them all in a single cell". What exactly do you need? 3 products per row, each in one cell?

Comment: Yes,3 products(with the its description image,product name and price) per row, each in one cell

Comment: there is a bug because if I remove one item in the database,the cells of the other items remain but their description disappear

Comment: There has to be some other logical problem... not  related to this loop.

Comment: I write this in the cell, <a href='contact.php'>Contact Seller</a>

Comment: how can I obtain the id of the product from the table which I have clicked??